# Best way to create a multiple windows WPF C# application?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm currently working on a school project where I'm asked to develop a C# WPF application. I'm implementing the MVVM design-pattern. This is why my main goal is to avoid using code-behind as much as I can. My main concern is that I'm trying to figure out an effective way around my software's "menu navigation" system.

For example, I'd like to have different windows to update clients, another to manage the employees and so on. My teacher said the best way would be to create an user control and adding it on every single window. How would that work? I would have to be able to detect the click on the user control and opening/loading the correct window according to that.

Comment: "This is why my main goal is to avoid using code-behind as much as I can."  That's not MVVM.  Use codebehind for your UI logic.  Use VMs for your business logic.

Comment: So, there's no better to handle the multiple windows issues other than just creating a new window and opening everytime and closing the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

And if you try to organize your projects in tabs with a TabControl? You can personalize it too!